# In Google Play, how can I delete my Beta testing channel?

Tags: alpha, beta, google-play-console

I set up both an Alpha and a Beta channel for testing my app and accidentally released code to the Beta channel having a release version of 1.0 and a version code of 0.1. I later disabled the Beta channel and created an Alpha channel that contains the current APK with a release version of 0.3 and version code of 0.6. But when testers select the test link, https://play.google.com/apps/testing/uomini.com.wegrok, they get the old Beta app.

I don't know why Google Play should be presenting testers with a disabled app, so I thought to delete the Beta version. Is there any way to do this? I can't do a rollout of the Alpha to Beta, for business reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was promoting my Alpha release to Beta. I had tried this earlier, but for some reason, it works now but didn't before.